# Changing basis from 3D space to plane coordinates

Tags: geometry

Let $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ be two normalized vector in a plane $P$ defined by a point $O_p$ and its normal vector $n_p$.

$M = (x, y, z)$ is a point in $P$, so its coordinates can be written as:

$\vec{O_pM_p} = t.\vec{u} + s.\vec{v}$ with $(t,s) \in \mathbb R $

$\vec{OM_p} = \vec{OO_p} + t.\vec{u} + s.\vec{v} $

The thing is when I write the equation system I come up with:

\begin{cases} x-O_x=s.u_x + t.v_x\\ y - O_y = s.u_y + t.v_y\\ z - O_z=s.u_z + t.v_z\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
t = \frac{(-O_y u_z + O_z u_y - u_y z + u_z y)}{(u_y (u_z - v_z))} \\ s = \frac{(-O_y m - O_z u_y + u_y z - v_z y)}{(u_y (u_z - v_z))} 
\end{cases}

Which is obviously wrong because $t$ and $s$ should depend on $x$. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: It's normal that $s$ and $t$ depend on the coordinates of $M$. What's wrong, exactly?

Comment: It's wrong because there's no $x$ in $t$ or $s$

Comment: That's not wrong: bear in mind that $M$ belongs to plane $P$, so its coordinates are not independent: you can usually eliminate one of them using the equation of $P$.

Comment: The system is supposed to work in general case, so $x$ is useless whatever $P$ possible. Imagine two orthogonal plans, there's no way $x$ can be omitted in both cases.

Plus experimentally I tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: You solved the system in a wrong way. But that has nothing to do with the presence of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Two of the equation of your system should be linearly independent: choose two of them and solve.

If, for instance, the second and third equation are independent, you get:
$$
s= \frac{-O_y v_z+O_z v_y-v_y z+v_z y}{-u_z v_y+u_yv_z},
\quad
t= \frac{O_y u_z-O_zu_y+u_y z-u_z y}{-u_z v_y+u_yv_z}.
$$
If they are not independent, however, you must choose another couple of equations.

EDIT.

If you want a more symmetric solution, construct two vectors $\vec u_\perp$ and $\vec v_\perp$ lying on plane $P$ and perpendicular to $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ respectively (for instance: $\vec u_\perp=\vec u\times\vec n_p$ and $\vec v_\perp=\vec v\times\vec n_p$). Your system of equations can be written in vector form as
$$
\vec M-\vec O=s\vec u + t\vec v.
$$
Taking the dot product of both sides first with $\vec u_\perp$ and then with $\vec v_\perp$, one of the unknowns cancels out, and one gets:
$$
s={(\vec M-\vec O)\cdot \vec v_\perp\over \vec u\cdot \vec v_\perp},
\quad
t={(\vec M-\vec O)\cdot \vec u_\perp\over \vec v\cdot \vec u_\perp}.
$$

Comment: In my case $(O, u, v)$ forms an orthonormal basis in $P$ so $u.v = 0$ and the $s$ and $t$'s denominator is necessarily 0.

Comment: @Deewy If $-u_zv_y+u_yv_z=0$ then use the first and second equation, instead of the second and third. You must use two linearly independent equations. Otherwise, just use the last version in my answer, which always works.

Answer (score 0):

You have a system of three equations in two unknows. It has no solution unless the equations aren't independent. Here it is indeed the case that they are dependent, because the point is constrained to be in the plane. So if $y,z$ are set, you have no more choice for $x$. In a way, $x$ appears implictly in the equations for $s,t$.

Comment: Ok I get it, the real question is how to find s and t knowing x,y,z ? That was what I attempted to do and my original question.

Comment: @Deewy What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: *three* unknowns should be *two* unknowns.

Comment: @Aretino I didn't read it yet

Comment: @Gribouillis: quite right, thanks.